# AHS: Murder House - Why does Moira have a discolored eye only in her older form?

Tags: american-horror-story

In the first season of American Horror Story, titled Murder House, the housemaid Moira is actually a ghost

> who has been killed after being shot in the eye by Constance Langdon.

She has two ghost forms; one as an old lady and the other with her actual appearance at the time of her death (younger version). Now, the older version has a discolored eye, which seems to be a homage to the way she died. However, her younger version, her actual appearance at the time of her death does not have a discolored eye. What is the reason behind this discrepancy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because Frances Conroy, the actress who plays the older version has a discolored eye in real life. Conroy had [met with a car accident](https://hitberry.com/what-is-the-deal-with-american-horror-story-star-frances-conroy-s-eyes) and the damage to the cornea of her right eye left it discolored. Because of this, **the way her character dies was modified** in the script to make her appearance more fitting. However, the younger version does not have this, as she is played by a different actress.

> Frances reportedly mentioned her eye problem when she was auditioning
> for "American Horror Story". The writers decided to make this into a
> plot point so that she would not have to wear contact lenses.